# Is a question about using the hammer function on a specific type of drill on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I inherited an old drill. It supposedly has a hammer function (it's a Black & Decker that calls itself Schlagbohrmaschine), but I don't know how to switch it on, and need help.

Is that too localised a question for this site? And if so, where should I ask?

Comment: So you're saying you had to stop because it was hammer time?

Comment: Schlagbohrmaschine is simply the German for hammer drill.

Comment: @Chenmunka Indeed. That's what initially made me suspect that there ought to be a hammer function somewhere on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about how to use a tool (which could be used for home improvement) are considered on-topic here. I'd recommend including a photo and steps you've taken to try to use it. Of course, if it's an old drill and you've tried the obvious, it may just be broken.

Comment: I'll just ask away, then.